# Rails Form with File Input Field - File just Name as String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input, file-upload

I want to embed a file input field in my form.
But on submit, the param value is just the file name, no StringIO or anything else, just a String with Filename.

Form:

```
    <%= form_tag(controller: 'search', action: 'confirm_new_search', method: 'post', multipart: true) do %>
        [....]
        <div class="custom-file field" id="inc_form">
          <%= file_field :post, :file_inc_sellerslist, class: "custom-file-input" %>
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="file_inc_sellerslist">
            <%= t('dashboard.new_search.extra_search_options_entries.choose_file') %>
          </label>
        </div>
        [....]
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `form_tag()` syntax is incorrect.  `form_tag` takes two hashes as arguments: one for the url, one for the html attributes.

> **form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)**
>
> Starts a form tag that points the action to a url configured with url_for_options just like ActionController::Base#url_for. The method
>   for the form defaults to POST.
>
> Options
>
> **:multipart** - If set to true, the enctype is set to
>   “multipart/form-data”.
>
> **:method** - The method to use when submitting the form, usually either
>   “get” or “post”. If “patch”, “put”, “delete”, or another verb is used,
>   a hidden input with name _method is added to simulate the verb over
>   post.
>
> **:authenticity_token** - Authenticity token to use in the form. Use only
>   if you need to pass custom authenticity token string, or to not add
>   authenticity_token field at all (by passing false). Remote forms may
>   omit the embedded authenticity token by setting
>   config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = false.
>   This is helpful when you're fragment-caching the form. Remote forms
>   get the authenticity token from the meta tag, so embedding is
>   unnecessary unless you support browsers without JavaScript.
>
> **:remote** - If set to true, will allow the Unobtrusive JavaScript
>   drivers to control the submit behavior. By default this behavior is an
>   ajax submit.
>
> **:enforce_utf8** - If set to false, a hidden input with name utf8 is not
>   output.
>
> **Any other key creates standard HTML attributes for the tag**.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

The following works for me:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: 'search', action: 'confirm_new_search'},
  method: 'post', 
  multipart: true) do %>
```

Here is an example of what happens with your form_tag() call:

```
def go(x={}, y={})
  p x
  p y
end

go(a: 1, b:2, c:3)

--output:
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
{}
```

As a result, all the key/value pairs you specified for `form_for()` are gathered into a hash and assigned to the parameter variable `url_for_options`.  The consequence of that is that your form_tag() isn't setting the html option `multipart` to true.  If you look at the source for your html, you will see:

```
<form action="/search/confirm_new_search?method=post&amp;multipart=true" 
      accept-charset="UTF-8" 
      method="post">
```

If you compare that html to your `form_tag()` call:

```
form_tag(controller: 'search', 
         action: 'confirm_new_search', 
         method: 'post', 
         multipart: true)
```

it's apparent that the last two key/value pairs get added to the query string in the url.  That behavior doesn't seem to be documented anywhere,  but the rule seems to be: for any key that `url_for()` doesn't recognize, the key and the corresponding value get added to the query string.  And, key/value pairs in the query string have nothing to do with html attributes for the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
form_tag({controller: 'search', action: 'confirm_new_search'}
, method: 'post', html: { multipart: true })
```

I faced the same issue and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Issue was `multipart: true` . Please add this to your view part.